# Mysql MAX ID+1 incriment with insert query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Please help in manually incrementing id filed with insert query and PDO
(note: No primary key set in table)

```
if ($valid) {
    $max="SELECT MAX(id)+1 from class";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO class (id,Class,Notes) values(?,?, ?)";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($max,$Class, $Notes));
    header("Location: class_create.php");
}
```

This insert not incrementing id, Please help

Comment: `$max` is just a string, not the result of the mysql query.

Comment: If you don't have a PRIMARY KEY, then, in a strict RDBMS sense, you don't really have a table. Just set the id as SERIAL and PRIMARY KEY, and forget about this 'manual' stuff.

Comment: You don't actually execute the first query. Why not use `AUTO_INCREMENT` on that column instead?

Comment: This makes very little sense. Why don't you just set the id to be an auto incremented primary key and let the database handle the auto inc automatically instead of manually trying to do it yourself? It's also prone to side effects. Ex. if the last record is removed, on the next insert, the new record would get the same ID as the deleted one. ID's should be unique and never reused.

Comment: @Strawberry, Thanks, I will set primary key with auto increment as well, 
i need similar incrementing in some other columns as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO class (id, Class, Notes) 
SELECT MAX(id)+1, ?, ?
FROM class
```

and

```php
$q->execute(array($Class, $Notes));
```

Be ready to duplicated values due to parallel execution interference.